# ASP.MVC how to route method as javasctipt library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I need to route method of MVC controller as js call script.

Have separated class library with controller:

```
[RouteArea("cms")]
public class ContentController : Controller
{
  [Route("cmslibrary.js", Name = "cmslib")]
  public ActionResult GetCMSJsLibrary()
  {   
     return new ContentResult()
     {
         Content = //<content of JS file goes yjere>
     }
  }
}
```

And somewhere in view inside of web ASP.MVC project:

```
@Scripts.Render(Url.RouteUrl("cmslib"))
```

And this renders:

```
/cms/cmslibrary.js
```

BUT: it returns 404 NotFound error. But if you try

```
/cms/cmslibrary.js/
```

all will work properly.

Probably MVC core checks if file physically exists and therefore iis returns 404 error.

Please help.

Comment: Could be a web server issue.  Are `.js` files handled by .NET?

Comment: just drop the '.js' from your route name. browsers dont care about extensions, they only care about the content-type header you send down

Comment: The IIS File Handler module will attempt to resolve this URL before it even gets to MVC. You could try adding `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />` to `web.config\<system.webServer>`, `AttributeRouting` might then be able to pick up that URL and serve the request. Otherwise @RobertLevy's solution is the way to go

Comment: you can also define the same in RoutingCOnfig